# What is the maltese pronounciation of 'għ' and 'ħ'?

Tags: pronunciation

In maltese :

-/ʕ/ and  /ɣ/ have merged into 'għ'. How is it pronounced?

-/ḥ/ and  /χ/ have merged into 'ħ'. How is it pronounced?

I've tried multiple youtube videos and :

-'għ' sounded nothing like /ʕ/ or /ɣ/ but like an 'a'.

-'ħ' sounded nothing like /ḥ/ and /χ/ but like an 'h'.

Makes me think that those speaking in these videos are not native speakers.

Comment: Can oyu link to the youtube videos that you're thinking of? Also, can you spell out exactly what your question is? Currently it is unclear what you want.

Comment: Please phrase your question in the form of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages-pronunciations/mt/).'ħ' is *like* Arabic 'ħ', but can be a bit different (but ħ is not really phonetically identical across all Arabic dialects). Likewise ħ (spelled x) in Somali is a bit different. Orthographic 'għ' is not standardly pronounced 'as such': this is the subject of a classic article by Mike Brame. Basically /ʕ/ behaves like *ʕ* throughout much of the phonology of Maltese, but then is vocalized to [a], deleted, or turned into [ħ] depending on context. There is much variation in Maltese dialects, and there are reports of dialects where ʕ is retained (a few hundred years ago).

Answer (score 1):

### ħ

In the International Phonetic Alphabet, this sound is written /ħ/ (conveniently enough): a voiceless pharyngeal fricative.

Since you mention ḥ, I'm guessing you've studied Arabic or a related language? It's like English /h/ but with a lowered larynx, or Arabic *ح*. /ħ/ is usually written *ḥ* when transcribing Arabic, though I personally prefer writing *ħ*.

### għ

This letter has a few different pronunciations. At the end of a word or before *h*, it's like *ħ*, but longer. Before a vowel, it lengthens and pharyngealizes it. According to Wikipedia, "*għi* and *għu* are [aˤj] and [oˤw]".